# How to get Phoenix to render multiple views in one call to render_many, for non related schemas

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Good Afternoon, I have an Elixir Phoenix API and I receive a Json with multiple data from two tables, Quota and clientsQuota, I managed to insert both tables using Ecto.Repo.insert_many/3 function. but I need to render both data in one json in one view, the data is as follows:

```
    [
  %{
    balance_sub_code: "123456789ABCDEF",
    bill_number: "0",
    delayed_quota_history_days: 0,
    due_date: ~U[2020-03-18 00:00:00Z],
    inte_adjust: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00001",
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_quota_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_state_sub_code: "UNKNOWN",
    prevision_amount: 0,
    quota_delayed_days: 0,
    quota_sec: 1,
    quota_state: "VIGENTE",
    start_date: ~U[2020-03-06 00:00:00Z]
  },
  %{
    balance_sub_code: "123456789ABCDEF",
    bill_number: "0",
    delayed_quota_history_days: 0,
    due_date: ~U[2020-03-25 00:00:00Z],
    inte_adjust: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00001",
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_quota_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_state_sub_code: "UNKNOWN",
    prevision_amount: 0,
    quota_delayed_days: 0,
    quota_sec: 2,
    quota_state: "APROBADO",
    start_date: ~U[2020-03-18 00:00:00Z]
  },
  %{
    balance_sub_code: "123456789ABCDEF",
    bill_number: "0",
    delayed_quota_history_days: 0,
    due_date: ~U[2020-03-18 00:00:00Z],
    inte_adjust: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00002",
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_quota_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_state_sub_code: "UNKNOWN",
    prevision_amount: 0,
    quota_delayed_days: 0,
    quota_sec: 1,
    quota_state: "VIGENTE",
    start_date: ~U[2020-03-06 00:00:00Z]
  },
  %{
    balance_sub_code: "123456789ABCDEF",
    bill_number: "0",
    delayed_quota_history_days: 0,
    due_date: ~U[2020-03-25 00:00:00Z],
    inte_adjust: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00002",
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_quota_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_state_sub_code: "UNKNOWN",
    prevision_amount: 0,
    quota_delayed_days: 0,
    quota_sec: 2,
    quota_state: "APROBADO",
    start_date: ~U[2020-03-18 00:00:00Z]
  }
]
```

and  for ClientsQuota is as follows:

```
    [
  %{
    calc_number_days: 12,
    concept_code: "CAPI",
    concept_state: "VIGENTE",
    condoned_amount: 0.0,
    debt_balance: 0.0,
    earned_amount: 22.77,
    last_payment_penalty: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00001",
    office_code: "Miio",
    paid_amount: 0.0,
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    payment_sec: 0,
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_concept_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_earned_amount: 0.0,
    previous_paid_amount: 0.0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_sec_payment: 0,
    quota_amount: 22.77,
    quota_sec: 1,
    user_code: "123456789ABCDEF"
  },
  %{
    calc_number_days: 12,
    concept_code: "INTE",
    concept_state: "VIGENTE",
    condoned_amount: 0.0,
    debt_balance: 0.0,
    earned_amount: 0.0,
    last_payment_penalty: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00001",
    office_code: "Miio",
    paid_amount: 0.0,
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    payment_sec: 0,
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_concept_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_earned_amount: 0.0,
    previous_paid_amount: 0.0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_sec_payment: 0,
    quota_amount: 5.63,
    quota_sec: 1,
    user_code: "123456789ABCDEF"
  },
  %{
    calc_number_days: 12,
    concept_code: "IVAIT",
    concept_state: "VIGENTE",
    condoned_amount: 0.0,
    debt_balance: 0.0,
    earned_amount: 0.0,
    last_payment_penalty: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00001",
    office_code: "Miio",
    paid_amount: 0.0,
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    payment_sec: 0,
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_concept_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_earned_amount: 0.0,
    previous_paid_amount: 0.0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_sec_payment: 0,
    quota_amount: 0.9,
    quota_sec: 1,
    user_code: "123456789ABCDEF"
  },
  %{
    calc_number_days: 7,
    concept_code: "CAPI",
    concept_state: "APROBADO",
    condoned_amount: 0.0,
    debt_balance: 0.0,
    earned_amount: 27.23,
    last_payment_penalty: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00001",
    office_code: "Miio",
    paid_amount: 0.0,
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    payment_sec: 0,
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_concept_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_earned_amount: 0.0,
    previous_paid_amount: 0.0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_sec_payment: 0,
    quota_amount: 27.23,
    quota_sec: 2,
    user_code: "123456789ABCDEF"
  },
  %{
    calc_number_days: 7,
    concept_code: "INTE",
    concept_state: "APROBADO",
    condoned_amount: 0.0,
    debt_balance: 0.0,
    earned_amount: 0.0,
    last_payment_penalty: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00001",
    office_code: "Miio",
    paid_amount: 0.0,
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    payment_sec: 0,
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_concept_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_earned_amount: 0.0,
    previous_paid_amount: 0.0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_sec_payment: 0,
    quota_amount: 1.79,
    quota_sec: 2,
    user_code: "123456789ABCDEF"
  },
  %{
    calc_number_days: 7,
    concept_code: "IVAIT",
    concept_state: "APROBADO",
    condoned_amount: 0.0,
    debt_balance: 0.0,
    earned_amount: 0.0,
    last_payment_penalty: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00001",
    office_code: "Miio",
    paid_amount: 0.0,
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    payment_sec: 0,
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_concept_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_earned_amount: 0.0,
    previous_paid_amount: 0.0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_sec_payment: 0,
    quota_amount: 0.29,
    quota_sec: 2,
    user_code: "123456789ABCDEF"
  },
  %{
    calc_number_days: 12,
    concept_code: "CAPI",
    concept_state: "VIGENTE",
    condoned_amount: 0.0,
    debt_balance: 0.0,
    earned_amount: 22.77,
    last_payment_penalty: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00002",
    office_code: "Miio",
    paid_amount: 0.0,
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    payment_sec: 0,
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_concept_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_earned_amount: 0.0,
    previous_paid_amount: 0.0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_sec_payment: 0,
    quota_amount: 22.77,
    quota_sec: 1,
    user_code: "123456789ABCDEF"
  },
  %{
    calc_number_days: 12,
    concept_code: "INTE",
    concept_state: "VIGENTE",
    condoned_amount: 0.0,
    debt_balance: 0.0,
    earned_amount: 0.0,
    last_payment_penalty: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00002",
    office_code: "Miio",
    paid_amount: 0.0,
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    payment_sec: 0,
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_concept_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_earned_amount: 0.0,
    previous_paid_amount: 0.0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_sec_payment: 0,
    quota_amount: 5.63,
    quota_sec: 1,
    user_code: "123456789ABCDEF"
  },
  %{
    calc_number_days: 12,
    concept_code: "IVAIT",
    concept_state: "VIGENTE",
    condoned_amount: 0.0,
    debt_balance: 0.0,
    earned_amount: 0.0,
    last_payment_penalty: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00002",
    office_code: "Miio",
    paid_amount: 0.0,
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    payment_sec: 0,
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_concept_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_earned_amount: 0.0,
    previous_paid_amount: 0.0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_sec_payment: 0,
    quota_amount: 0.9,
    quota_sec: 1,
    user_code: "123456789ABCDEF"
  },
  %{
    calc_number_days: 7,
    concept_code: "CAPI",
    concept_state: "APROBADO",
    condoned_amount: 0.0,
    debt_balance: 0.0,
    earned_amount: 27.23,
    last_payment_penalty: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00002",
    office_code: "Miio",
    paid_amount: 0.0,
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    payment_sec: 0,
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_concept_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_earned_amount: 0.0,
    previous_paid_amount: 0.0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_sec_payment: 0,
    quota_amount: 27.23,
    quota_sec: 2,
    user_code: "123456789ABCDEF"
  },
  %{
    calc_number_days: 7,
    concept_code: "INTE",
    concept_state: "APROBADO",
    condoned_amount: 0.0,
    debt_balance: 0.0,
    earned_amount: 0.0,
    last_payment_penalty: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00002",
    office_code: "Miio",
    paid_amount: 0.0,
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    payment_sec: 0,
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_concept_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_earned_amount: 0.0,
    previous_paid_amount: 0.0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_sec_payment: 0,
    quota_amount: 1.79,
    quota_sec: 2,
    user_code: "123456789ABCDEF"
  },
  %{
    calc_number_days: 7,
    concept_code: "IVAIT",
    concept_state: "APROBADO",
    condoned_amount: 0.0,
    debt_balance: 0.0,
    earned_amount: 0.0,
    last_payment_penalty: "A",
    loan_code: "999-399-06-00-00002",
    office_code: "Miio",
    paid_amount: 0.0,
    payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:00Z],
    payment_sec: 0,
    plan_number: 0,
    previous_concept_state: "UNKNOWN",
    previous_earned_amount: 0.0,
    previous_paid_amount: 0.0,
    previous_payment_date: ~U[1970-01-01 00:00:01Z],
    previous_sec_payment: 0,
    quota_amount: 0.29,
    quota_sec: 2,
    user_code: "123456789ABCDEF"
  }
]
```

I tried this in View code but got Errors:

can not render function render_many.json in Cabbot.CreditsView.ex.

```
def render("render_many.json", [
        %{quota: quota},
        %{quota: quota},
        %{clients_quota: clients_quota},
        %{clients_quota: clients_quota},
        %{clients_quota: clients_quota},
        %{clients_quota: clients_quota},
        %{clients_quota: clients_quota},
        %{clients_quota: clients_quota}
      ]) do
    %{data: render_many(quota, CreditsView, "credits_quota.json")}
    %{data: render_many(clients_quota, CreditsView, "credits_quota.json")}
  end
```

Any help will be deeply apreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A repetitive argument in the function clause results in pattern matching on this argument.

```elixir
defmodule Test do
  def foo(a, a), do: :same
  def foo(_, _), do: :diff
end

Test.foo(42, 42) #⇒ :same
Test.foo(41, 42) #⇒ :diff
```

That said, your function is unlikely to be ever called. What you need instead, would be to split the input with [`Enum.split_with/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#split_with/2) somewhat like below

```elixir
def render("render_many.json", input) do
  {quota, clients_quota} = Enum.split_with(input, fn
    %{quota: _} -> true
    %{clients_quota: _} -> false
  end)

  # do whatever you need with the outcome here
end
```